# Using python requests module to login on an Wordpress based website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to login to a Wordpress based website using python's request module and beautifulsoup4. It seems like the code fails to sucessfully login. Also, there is no csrf token on the website. How do I sucessfully login to the website?

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs
with requests.session() as c: 
    link="https://gpldl.com/sign-in/" #link of the webpage to be logged in
    initial=c.get(link) #passing the get request

    login_data={"log":"*****","pwd":"******"} #the login data from any account on the site. Stars must be replaced with username and password
    page_login=c.post(link, data=login_data) #posting the login data into the link
    print(page_login) #checking status of requested page
    page=c.get("https://gpldl.com/my-gpldl-account/") #requesting source code of logged in page

    good_data = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml") #parsing it with BS4
    print(good_data.title) #printing this gives the title that is got from the page when accessed from an logged-out account
```

Comment: hello dear Arun Kumar A - many thanks for coming up with this question - this is great. I really like this idea. It is great. Many  thanks for sharing your approach with us. You helped me alot. Keep up  the  great work  - all the best to you!!! Greetings and regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending your POST request to a wrong URL, the correct one should be `https://gpldl.com/wp-login.php`, also there're 5 parameters for the payload which are `log`, `pwd`, `rememberme`, `redirect_to`, `redirect_to_automatic`.

So it should be:

```
login_data = {"log": "*****","pwd": "******", 
              "rememberme": "forever", 
              "redirect_to": "https://gpldl.com/my-gpldl-account/", 
              "redirect_to_automatic": "1"
             }

page_login = c.post('https://gpldl.com/wp-login.php', data=login_data)
```

**Edit:**

You could use Chrome Dev tool to find out all these info while logging in, it's like this:

[image: Login]

As to `rememberme` key, I would suggest you to do exact same thing a browser does, also add some headers for your request, especially `User-Agent`, because for some websites they just don't welcome you got login this way.

Comment: I'm all new to this. Thank you so much. I have a query. The exact URL to which the POST request is to be made is determined by analyzing the name of the POST request in Network tab on the Inspect Element option in chrome. Am I right? And is the "rememberme" key necessary? I don't see it listed in that POST request file.

Comment: @ArunKumarA Check my edit, you could use Chrome Dev Tools (press F12) to find out what's happening behind the scenes. You'd better stick with all those parameters, this way you don't get blocked by some websites.

Comment: hi there Shane many thanks for sharing your solution with us - i am currently ironing out a solution for login to the forums here: https://wordpress.org/support/forums/ 
i think that with your code i finally will be able to get there.  There is a way to achive this. Again - many thanks diear Shane. - yours Zero

Comment: well - i guess that Is best to try with Selenium on that login,as it use Google reCaptcha V3 token when login.If think it's Browser then can maybe bypass it.- so dear Shane i guess that the best setup we can use is the one with selnium .- wht do you think!?